# JQuery doesn't recognize 'tbody' and 'tr' of datatable using hover() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am working with a datatable and trying to create a hover window which will display data from the datatable and a picture, not important, thing is I am trying to append a div with premade css classes for this project into either a cell or row using hover(), but jquery doesn't recognize the body and row of the datatable. Here is a fiddle I tested it on https://jsfiddle.net/r6tbv9uz/6/ and it works just fine, 
and here is a code I am using in the project:

```
$('.datatable-sort').find('tbody').hover(
    function () {
        console.log('hovered in');
        var iDiv = CreateHoverElement();//the div is a bit complex so I have separate function for it
        var element = $(this).closest('tr');
        element.append(iDiv);
    },
    function () {
        var element = document.getElementById('tablehover');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        console.log('hovered out');
    }
);
```

The thing is when I use the hover as such:

```
$('.datatable-sort').hover(function(){...},function(){...})
```

The hover function works perfectly but that wont help me as I need the hover out part to work within a row and only in tbody.
I have tried lot of googling around and lot of trial and error but can't figure it out, if anyone has ideas i would appriciate it, Thanks.

EDIT: html snippet of the datatable:

```
<table class="table table-striped datatable-sort compact fixedHeader-locked">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Time</th>               <!--Created-->
                        <th scope="col">Lane</th>               <!--LaneNumber-->
                        <th scope="col">Credence(%)</th>        <!--Credence-->
                        <th scope="col">LPN</th>                <!--Plate-->
                        <th scope="col">LPN(%)</th>             <!--PlateConfidence-->
                        <th scope="col">Country</th>            <!--CountryCode-->
                        <th scope="col">Country(%)</th>         <!--CountryConfidence-->
                        <th scope="col">Speed(km/h)</th>        <!--Speed-->
                        <th scope="col">Speed change(km/h)</th> <!--SpeedDifference-->
                        <th scope="col">Width(cm)</th>          <!--Width-->
                        <th scope="col">Height(cm)</th>         <!--Height-->
                        <th scope="col">Length(cm)</th>         <!--Length-->
                        <th scope="col">Weight(kg)</th>         <!--Weight-->
                        <th scope="col">Axles</th>              <!--Axles-->
                        <th scope="col">VehicleID</th>          <!--ID-->
                        <th scope="col">ClassEUR13</th>         <!--Classification-->
                        <th scope="col">Version</th>            <!--null-->
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>              <!--null-->
                        <th scope="col">Direction</th>          <!--Direction-->
                        <th scope="col">Certainty</th>          <!--null-->
                        <th scope="col">Axles Count</th>        <!--AxleCount-->
                        <th scope="col">Gross Weight</th>       <!--null-->
                        <th scope="col">Axles 1 weight(kg)</th> <!--Axles[0].Weight-->
                        <th scope="col">Axles 2 weight(kg)</th> <!--Axles[1].Weight-->
                        <th scope="col">Heading (sec)</th>      <!--Height-->
                        <th scope="col">Gap (sec)</th>          <!--Gap-->
                        <th scope="col">Digital Signature</th>  <!--null-->
                        <th scope="col">Checksum</th>           <!--Checksum-->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

Rows are added to the table via JS script.

Comment: where is your HTML ?

Comment: Edited and added the snippet for the table, the whole html has a lot in it so hope the table snippet is enough, if not let me know, thanks!

Comment: In your fiddle, I could see the cosole.log working fine.What is exactly not working? Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt the hover function procs properly on datatable itself but when i go on with .find('tbody') jquery doesnt recognize it, or the hover function, cant really tell from the debugging. I am trying implement the fiddle structure to my code so the hover procs when i hover over a row as in the fiddle but it does not work in my project.

Comment: @Pato Srna, But where is the <tbody> tag in your HTML that you have posted? It only has <thead> tag as far as I can see

Comment: If your `<tbody>` contents are being loaded dynamically in JavaScript (I suspect this because there is no `<tbody>` in your snippet above), then you need to delegate the event handler...

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt its generated by js, rows are added using js aswell

Comment: @War10ck does that mean that there is no event listener on the elements that are created dynamically and i have to attach one? if so would you be so kind and point me to some readings on how to do this? thanks!

Comment: @PatoSrna Yes that's correct. If an element is not present in the DOM when the event is bound, the element will not react to the event handler. I've created a delegated version of your `hover` handler below in my answer. Check it out and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are adding these elements dynamically. If that is correct, then the event handlers when they are defined are not able to attach to the elements themselves because they are not present in the DOM at the time of binding. To solve this, try using dynamic event handlers:

```
$('.datatable-sort').on('mouseenter', 'tbody', function () {
        console.log('hovered in');
        var iDiv = CreateHoverElement();//the div is a bit complex so i have separate function for it
        var element = $(this).closest('tr');
        element.append(iDiv);
    }).on('mouseleave', 'tbody', function () {
        var element = document.getElementById('tablehover');
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        console.log('hovered out');
    });
```

I'm not aware of a way to delegate the `.hover()` event but according to the docs for [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), it is a shorthand syntax for two events: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so delegating each of these should provide the same effect.

Comment: Thank you very much! altho its not removing the div afterwards but i think i can work that out, the event triggers now and that is what i couldnt work out so lots of thanks to you!